# Broken/Missing Handers in View

Tags: views

So one of my views has a few broken/missing handlers. It was working fine up until yesterday. I run `composer update --no-dev --with-dependacies` and a lot of files updated. After which i run `drush updb` and `drush entup` .A lot of files were updated. As far as i can tell, only views were affected. 
This view is an ordinary view, you can see in image bellow.[image: View with broken/missing hanlders]

Those missing hanlders were ordinary fields, two were textfields and last one was a media entity.
When i try to remove the handlers, and add those fields again they are not in the list of available fields, **as a matter of fact no custom fields [over 30], are available to be added** only the default fields [Id, title, revision], not even the Body field is there.

One thing i did find, is that one of my colleagues run a db_script which was supposed to back up certain db_tables, but it only emptied the tables [affected tables were: key_value, key_value_expire, media, router, sessions].

composer.json:

```
{
"name": "drupal/drupal",
"description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0+",
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1.3",
    "drupal/core": "^8.5",
    "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^1.6",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.1",
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.7",
    "drupal/adminimal_admin_toolbar": "^1.0",
    "drupal/token": ">=1.0",
    "drupal/rules": "3.0-alpha3",
    "drupal/search_api_solr": "^1.2",
    "drupal/ctools": "3.0",
    "symfony/property-access": "^3.2",
    "drupal/salesforce": "^3.0@RC",
    "drupal/dynamic_entity_reference": "^2.0",
    "drupal/features": "^3.5",
    "drupal/crop": "^2.0",
    "drupal/focal_point": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/dropzonejs": "^2.0",
    "drupal/config_ignore": "^2.1",
    "drupal/embed": "^1.0",
    "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.0",
    "drupal/media_entity": "^2.0",
    "drupal/acquia_connector": "^1.14",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.0",
    "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.4",
    "drupal/metatag": "^1.4",
    "drupal/reroute_email": "^1.0",
    "drupal/devel": "^1.2",
    "drupal/kint": "^1.2",
    "drupal/twig_xdebug": "^1.0",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/config_filter": "^1.2",
    "drupal/entity":"^1.0",
    "drupal/entity_block": "^1.0",
    "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.0",
    "drupal/file_browser": "^1.1",
    "drupal/inline_entity_form":"^1.0",
    "drupal/media_entity_image": "^1.2",
    "drupal/smtp":"^1.0",
    "drupal/typed_data":"^1.0",
    "drupal/viewfield":"^3.0",
    "drupal/media_entity_actions":"^1.0"

},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
},
"extra": {
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": false,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "profiles/schools/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "profiles/schools/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
        "profiles/schools/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
        "profiles/schools/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess"
    ],
    "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
],
"require-dev": {
}
```

}

Drupal 8.5.4
Drupal status: 0 errors, 1 notice [irrelevant to this]

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** fixed [partially], i imported the data for the `key_value` & `key_value_expire` tables from another database (my dev db).

Comment: Try to run `www.mysite.com/update.php` in the browser. Since D8.4 I had a lot of trouble with drush updb and at the moment I use only update.php. And don't run `drush entup`, it destroys data if applied at the wrong time.

Comment: @4k4 I tried but when i do i get the following error message which just confuses me even further as i can't see how it's even possible. Error name: "MINIMUM SCHEMA VERSION", error message: "Your system schema version is -1. Updating directly from a schema version prior to 8000 is not supported. You must upgrade your site to Drupal 8 first". Core is 8.5.4 and all modules are up to date with no errors/notices.

Comment: This is probably what happens if you empty the key_value table.

Comment: @4k4 You're probably right, been reading in detail the relationship between key_value & key_value_expire and the rest of the db. I took a mysqldump of my dev DB and updated those two tables with values from the dev DB, cleared the cache and did a drush updb, problem has resolved itself, i did get a few notices, but it's better than how it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the fields were removed during the update, but Views' config is still trying to look for them. If you have them in configuration somewhere, just import them. If not, I'd suggest removing the broken fields in Views, creating all the fields you need in the entity and check Views again. When you get it working take a config export!